# In Logic app HTTP action how to use multiple values into $filter?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In logic app I want to use multiple values into $filter

```
"HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "headers": {
                        "Authorization": "mytoken",
                        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "key"
                    },
                    "method": "GET",
                    "queries": {
                        "$filter": "(Number eq '123')"
```

I want to check `Number` with `123, 456 , 898`

how can i add multiple values into above $filter statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `"$filter": "(Number eq '123' or Number eq '456' or Number eq '898')"`, besides, without `()`, it will also work.

Test with an Azure REST API:

[image]

[image]

Comment: actually this should have to work but for my APIM url it is not working 
getting below error -
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

Comment: @Neo Hi, Neo, I am sorry that I am not familiar with APIM, you may need to ask it in a new question.